# How to reassign values in pandas columns, conditional on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've created the following sample dataframe:

```
data = {'min_year': [2000, 2002, 2008], 'max_year': [2001, 2005, 2010]}
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

all_years = sorted(list(set(list(data['min_year'])+list(data['max_year']))))

for year in all_years:
    data[year] = 1
    
print(data)

   min_year  max_year  2000  2001  2002  2005  2008  2010
0      2000      2001     1     1     1     1     1     1
1      2002      2005     1     1     1     1     1     1
2      2008      2010     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

If the year-column is not between min_year and max_year, I would like to reassign its value to 0, as follows:

```
   min_year  max_year  2000  2001  2002  2005  2008  2010
0      2000      2001     1     1     0     0     0     0
1      2002      2005     0     0     1     1     0     0
2      2008      2010     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

The following attempt to set years before min_year to 0 yields funky results, and applying the same method for years after max_year sets all years to zero:

```
for year in all_years:
    data[year].loc[data['min_year'] < year] = 0

print(data)

   min_year  max_year  2000  2001  2002  2005  2008  2010
0      2000      2001     1     0     0     0     0     0
1      2002      2005     1     1     1     0     0     0
2      2008      2010     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list of dictionaries by `range`s, then convert to DataFrame and join to original instead your solution:

```
data = {'min_year': [2000, 2002, 2008], 'max_year': [2001, 2005, 2010]}
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

L = [dict.fromkeys(range(a, b+1), 1) for a, b in data[['min_year','max_year']].to_numpy()]

df = data.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=data.index).fillna(0).astype(int))
print(df)
   min_year  max_year  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2008  2009  2010
0      2000      2001     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1      2002      2005     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2      2008      2010     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

In your solution should be used numpy brodcasting for compare by columns names:

```
m1 = data['max_year'].to_numpy()[:, None] >= np.array(all_years)
m2 = data['min_year'].to_numpy()[:, None] <= np.array(all_years)

data[all_years] = data[all_years].where(m1, 0).where(m2, 0)
   min_year  max_year  2000  2001  2002  2005  2008  2010
0      2000      2001     1     1     0     0     0     0
1      2002      2005     0     0     1     1     0     0
2      2008      2010     0     0     0     0     1     1
```